# Find the smallest positive value of x for which the gradient is...

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Morning,

I would really appreciate a hint towards what i'm missing with the following problem. Is there an identity I should be employing/have I done something stupid?

Find the smallest positive value of $x$ for which the gradient is $1$

$y = \cos x - 2\sin x$

I know

$dy/dx$ = $-\sin x - 2\cos x$

When $dy/dx$ $= 1$

$-\sin x - 2\cos x$ = 1

But from here onwards my working seems to go round in circles. I've tried squaring it all to use the identity $\cos^2$$x$ $+ \sin^2 x$ $= 1$ but it isn't proving very helpful to me.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you left:
$$-\sin x - 2\cos x = 1$$
Squaring on both sides:
$$ \sin^2 x = (1+2\cos x)^2$$
$$ \sin^2 x = 1 + 4\cos^2 x + 4\cos x$$
Now from the $1st$ equation, $4\cos x = -2(\sin x + 1)$. Now substituting this in the above equation:
$$ \sin^2 x = 1 + 4(1 - \sin^2 x) - 2(\sin x + 1)$$
$$ 5\sin^2 x + 2\sin x - 3 = 0$$
$$ (\sin x - \frac{3}{5})(\sin x + 1) = 0$$
So finally we get:
$$ \sin x = {\frac{3}{5}, -1}$$
Since we need the smallest positive $x$, $\sin x = \frac{3}{5}$, because $x$ lies in the first quadrant where as for $\sin x = -1$, $x$ lies beyond $1st$ quadrant.

Hence $x = 0.644$

Comment: Thank you, this was clear. Is the best way to recognise which relationships to use, simply to do a lot of questions?

Comment: Sorry did not get you. Can you be more clear with what you meant by relationships ?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid squaring as it immediately introduces [Extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) roots

Continuing from where you left of  $−\sin x−2\cos x=1$

Using   [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution),

$$-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=1\iff 2t+2(1-t^2)+1+t^2=0$$ where $\displaystyle t=\tan\frac x2$

Solving for $\displaystyle t,t=-1,3$

$\displaystyle t=-1\implies \sin x=\frac{2(-1)}{1+(-1)^2}=-1$

$\displaystyle t=3\implies \sin x=\frac{2\cdot3}{1+3^2}=\frac35$

Comment: @Jacobadtr, how about this?

Comment: I can follow along what you've done and have used the half angle identities to solve equations before. Point taken about extraneous roots also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the final expression that you reached:

$$-\sin(x)-2\cos(x)=1 \implies \sin(x)+2\cos(x)=-1$$

Using the fact that $\cos^{2}(x)+\sin^{2}(x)\equiv 1$ we get $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}$, using this in your equation we get:

$$\sin(x)+2\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}=-1 \implies -(1+\sin(x))=2\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}$$

Squaring both sides of the equation we get:

$$1+2\sin(x)+\sin^{2}(x)=4-4\sin^{2}(x) \implies 5\sin^{2}(x)+2\sin(x)-3 = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation in $\sin(x)$, which we can solve to get:

$$\sin(x)=\left\{-1,\frac{3}{5}\right\}$$

Taking inverse sine we get:

$$x=\left\{-\frac{\pi}{2},\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\right\}\approx\left\{-1.5708,0.6435\right\}$$

So the smallest positive $x$ for which $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=1$ is $x=0.6435$.

Comment: Thank you, this method also makes sense

Comment: Extravagant. You don't have to know much to solve it.